# Repeated measures test against baseline

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, repeated-measures, random-field

I have data from a field experiment and I want to identify if it's reasonable to test against a baseline mean to show that the ratings are significantly greater.

These are the characteristcs of the intervention delivery and the measurements:

- Ten participants were involved
- After the intervention, people rated from 1 (no effect) to 5 (strong effect) the impact of the intervention
- Interventions were randomly assigned over 2 months
- Each participant did a different amount of each intervention (but each intervention for each participant was done more than 6 times)
- One intervention did not differ at all, the second intervention differed slightly in each run

For the comparison of the interventions, I run a repeated measures ANOVA (e.g. if the effect of one of the interventions is significantly perceived greater than the other).

Now my question is, is it reasonable to test if participants significantly rate the intervention greater than 3 (medium effects)? Is this a reasonable comparison? A t-test seems not applicable as measurements between participants are probably dependent as they have conducted the same intervention several times? How would I do it?

Comment: It seems to me that you may use [Wilcoxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test)'s test to compare the impact of the intervention with the number $3$. If the mean rank of the impact of the intervention is significantly higher than the mean rank of $3$, you could say that the impact is significantly stronger than $3$.

Comment: @Ertxiem-reinstateMonica thanks!
You propose Wilcoxon's test as the intervention reponses per participants won't be normally distributed? Else could I use a dependent sample t-test?

Do I have somehow to consider that the participants have their own mean (what I do with a repeated measures ANOVA)? In your proposed approach, I would use all measurements over all participants by intervention to compare it against my fixed value?